# How do you skip cutscenes?

Tags: la-noire

They are getting annoying when you need to replay a failed chase or something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press "A" Button on Xbox controller to skip a cutscene. Note that certain scenes, such as the start of a case and key conversations, cannot be bypassed.

Agent86, thanks for the answer in a comment.

Answer (score 4):

You can skip a cutscene on the PC version of the game by pressing "Backspace".

Answer (score 1):

I dont think its <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. You have to hold the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button.

Comment: This sounds like a comment to another answer. Are you sure it's Enter?

Comment: Maybe the release in 2017 changed the button to skip?

Answer (score 0):

For the PS3 version, hold the start button and then press the X button.